# Trigonometry Identities

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Consider a collection of ﬁve points evenly spaced around a circle to form a regular
pentagon. Assume the ﬁgure is scaled so that the sides of the pentagon have length 1.
Question: Use Ptolemy’s theorem to calculate the distance between non-adjacent vertices.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the vertices of the pentagon, in counterclockwise order, be $A,B,C,D,E$. Consider the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$. Let $x=AC=BD=DA$. By Ptolemy's Theorem, we have $(x)(x)=(1)(1)+(x)(1)$. Solve the quadratic equation, using the Quadratic Formula.